# Eclipse DLTK does not dysplay TCL puts command in console

Tags: eclipse, tcl

I don't see a TCL puts commands output in standart Eclipse Console in debug mode, but i see them in Relise mode.
Any ideas?

I tryed in Eclipse Neon and Luna with DLTK and debuger from Komodo 9 and 10. The result is the same. Also i don't see a standart console in list of avalible windows in debug mode.

[image: No output in console]

Comment: I'd expect that to Just Work. OTOH, I'm inclined to just paste code into tkcon (or a real console).

Comment: Strange, but in videos about DLTK output of puts command displayed in console in debug mode

Comment: problem solved by installing Eclipse Neon for C/C++ developers (Eclipse CDT) and all components of DLTK plagin.